# how to get value of url in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, passbook

I have this route:

`Route::post('/apns/v1/devices/{device_token}/registrations/{pass_identifier}/{pass_serial}', 'ApiController@registrations');`

How do i get the values of device_token, pass_identifier and pass_serial and save them in a variable in my controller?

For example:

`POST /v1/devices/3252362643/registrations/passtype.test/4312`

i want to get the value `3252362643`, `passtype.test` and `4312`.

save them in variables in Laravel controller.

Comment: Is that a Laravel url or do you just get this as a string value?

Comment: thats a POST request.. this is for my api..

Comment: What do you have so far? Can we see your code to help you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the route parameters by using the `request()` helper:

```
$device_token = request()->route()->parameter('device_token')

$pass_identifier = request()->route()->parameter('pass_identifier')

$pass_serial = request()->route()->parameter('pass_serial')
```

Answer (score 0):

In controller:

```
public function registrations($device_token, $pass_identifier, $pass_serial)
{
   //insert to DB
   $data = new User; //your model
   $data->device_token= $device_token;
   $data->pass_identifier= $pass_identifier;
   $data->pass_serial= $pass_serial;
   $data->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Follow "Ilya Yaremchuk" and "btl" method... this one is alternative method

**In this case you can get those value from $ss, $ss1, $ss2**

```
**Add this in your laravel controller**


   $url = 'POST /v1/devices/3252362643/registrations/passtype.test/4312';
        $names = explode('/', $url);
            if (!empty($names)) {
                $ss = $names[3];
                $ss1 = $names[5];
                $ss2 = $names[6];
            }
```

> or try this

```
         $names = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
         if (!empty($names)) {
             $ss = $names[3];
             $ss1 = $names[5];
             $ss1 = $names[6];
          }
```

Comment: Whether you get the answer or not?